# Slitherlink with a 4

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

Yesterday, I got my pen-pal to teach me the rules of Slitherlink. I had to use a translator to understand what she wrote though, and as a result I suspect I've misunderstood some of her points. I've tried all of the Slitherlink puzzles on this site, but I think none of them have valid solutions!

Oh well. If I can't solve others' puzzles, I'll just have to create my own.

**Can you find the unique solution to the following Slitherlink I created, and tell me how I have misunderstood the rules?**

[image: Slitherlink puzzle]

[Click here for an interactive version.](https://puzz.link/p?slither/v:/6/6/h8d68da2cgchd59b) (Note that the "check" button does *not* work correctly for this puzzle.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The misunderstanding:

> In your grid, the numbers indicate how many corner points the loop passes through.

The solution:

> [image]

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for explaining! (And well done on the quick solve.)

Comment: Interesting new puzzle type.  I don't think I have seen that variant before.